# Chrome contextmenu extension: save selected text into a variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, selection

I am trying to create an extension that will search the selected word into a dictionary. I am trying to get the selected text into a variable in JavaScript but it's not working.
Here is the code:

```
var search= {
    "id": "searchurl",
    "title": "Search on dictionary",
    "contexts": ["selection"]

};

chrome.contextMenus.create(search);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData){
    "use strict";
    if (clickData.menuItemId === "searchurl" && clickData.selectionText){
        var urlkey = Document.getSelection().toString();
        alert(urlkey);

    }

});
```

I have included jquery to make it work on chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clickData.selectionText` already has your selected text.

```
var search = {
    "id": "searchurl",
    "title": "Search on dictionary",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(search);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData) {
    if (clickData.menuItemId === "searchurl" && clickData.selectionText) {
        alert(clickData.selectionText)
    }
});
```